# Removing message box for max input in html i

Tags: html, max, tooltip, hint

The browser is adding a message about the maximum value allowed. How to remove this?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min
Reproduce: Type in the input value above max, keep the curser in the input, move the mouse outside, then inside the input, wait. You will get the message. How to remove it??

[image]

Comment: remove the max/min attributes

Comment: But I want to have a max control without a tooltip as I add a custom tooltip!

Comment: create your own custom size limiting function - you cannot, afaik, alter the default behaviour of the browser in this regard.

Comment: sounds like adding title="" solves it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an empty `title` attribute on the input field. This maintains the form validation on submit.

```
<input title="" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```